# feval taking a lot of time in matlab ga optimization

Tags: performance, matlab, genetic-algorithm

I am running a ga optimization and a lot of time is wasted in feval line of fcnvectorizer.m. This is an private function of ga optimization. I have run profiler and following are the results.

The fitness function is called 1600 times and it takes a total of 9.8 seconds.

The following fval line is called a total of 1600 times and it takes a total of 117 seconds.

```
      y(i,:) = feval(fun,(pop(i,:)));
```

Here, fun is the function handle of my fitness function. The above line should simply call the fitness function and assign results to y vector. I fail to understand why simple calling of fitness function takes so much time.

I am using Matlab 7.9.0(R2009b) and following is the output of memory command

```
Maximum possible array:              25346 MB (2.658e+010 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:     25346 MB (2.658e+010 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:                 661 MB (6.936e+008 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):               16324 MB (1.712e+010 bytes)
```

Snippet of code to start ga:

```
 contract='NIFTY';
 dates=all_dates([20140801 20140831]); % all_dates between given two dates
 options=gaoptimset('PopInitRange',Bound,'PopulationSize',100,...
    'EliteCount',2, 'Generations',16,'StallGenL',8,...
    'Display','iter');
options.dates=dates;
for i=1:length(dates)
   options.data(i)=loaddata(contract,dates(i)); %loaddata is custom function to load data for a particular date.
end
fitnessFcn=@(x)fitness(x,options);
[x,fval] = ga(fitnessFcn,8,options);
```

Comment: Could you provide a pice of code to reproduce the behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not figure out to improve feval. So decided to bypass it altogether.

Set options.Vectorized='on' and modified the fitness function to take array of inputs.